# How do you add an object to a specific collection only in python?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I made this short script. Why is the new object being added to the default collection? Can I get around unlinking the object, not linking it in the first place? How do you add an object only to a specific collection in python?

```
if (bpy.data.collections.find('Tiles') == True):
    tiles_collection = bpy.data.collections['Tiles']
else:
    tiles_collection = bpy.data.collections.new('Tiles')
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(tiles_collection)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(1, -5, 0), size=1)

basemesh = bpy.context.object

tiles_collection.objects.link(basemesh)

bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.unlink(basemesh)
```

This is what the outliner looks like without the last line in the script:

[image]

Comment: I read your question many times, and failed to understand what are you trying to achieve, please re-organize your question in a clearer way, state clearly what is the result you're getting now, and what is the result you're wishing to achieve.

Comment: i hope that made it clearer

Comment: I tried to make a question out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add` ...

... is doing stuff behind your back, based on the current `context`. It's creating the mesh, then an object from it, and linking it to the `context`'s active `collection`. So when you call `link`, it's linking for the second time.

You could make the 'Tiles' collection active, and let `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add`  do its own thing in there...

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data


if D.collections.get('Tiles'):
    tiles_collection = D.collections['Tiles']
else:
    tiles_collection = D.collections.new('Tiles')
    C.scene.collection.children.link(tiles_collection)

C.view_layer.active_layer_collection = \
C.view_layer.layer_collection.children['Tiles']

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(1, -5, 0), size=1)
```

... I'm not saying it's a great thing to do, that would take someone with more experience than me. It may be better not to call `bpy.ops.xxx` at all, to avoid `context` connected activity, or the way you're doing it now may be just fine.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!